# Is Time.deltaTime different on various devices?

Tags: unity, c#, timer, timestep, fixed-timestep

Can someone say what is wrong with my code. I have custom timer implemented like this:

```
 float timeRemain = 10f;
 void Update(){
 timeRemain -= Time.deltaTime;
 if(timeRemain <= 0){
  ///...code here.
   }
 }
```

On PC it runs like expected but on Android device `timeRemain` variable becomes 0 in less then 10 secs. Who can suggest me what happens when i run it on Android device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On some platforms the game actually starts running before the splash screen is gone. So this may give the illusion of a defective timer if you test it right at the start.

Another issue on slow devices is that your first frame of timer activation may have a very large `deltaTime` if other things happen at the same time.

For example if it takes 2 seconds to transfer all the textures and meshes to GPU memory on the first frame the timer is activated then the perceived display time will be 8 seconds because whatever was to be shown was invisible for the 2 seconds hang.

The `deltaTime` is the time the **previous** frame took.

Other than these two gotchas, `deltaTime` acts in an identical fashion on all platforms.